# Move single or multiple sequential items in a list to any position

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need to move single or multiple sequential items in a list, by sequential I mean if the items are more than one there are no gaps in their list indexes, here is what I have tried...

```py
def move(x, tomove, idx):
    move_start = tomove[0]
    move_end = tomove[-1] + 1
    if idx == len(x) or idx == len(x) - 1:
        return x[:move_start] + x[move_end:] + x[move_start:move_end]
    elif idx == 0:
        return x[move_start:move_end] + x[:move_start] + x[move_end:]
    else:
        pass

# move to start
print (move([0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
            [2],
            0))
# expected output [2,0,1,3,4,5,6]

# move to end
print (move([0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
            [2],
            6))
# expected output [0,1,3,4,5,6,2]

# move forward single
print (move([0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
            [2],
            3))
# expected output [0,1,3,2,4,5,6]

# move backward single
print (move([0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
            [2],
            1))
# expected output [0,2,1,3,4,5,6]

# move forward multiple
print (move([0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
            [2,3],
            5))
# expected output [0,1,4,5,2,3,6]

# move backward multiple
print (move([0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
            [4,5],
            2))
# expected output [0,1,4,5,2,3,6]
```

Comment: I might not understood it completely, but have you considered this simple approach? [online compiler](https://repl.it/repls/ImportantReadyDirectory)

Comment: @andreis11 sorry, I have updated my question with more expected output examples which include multiple list indexes to be moved

Comment: @andreis11 just in case you're answering the question, I have just changed the expected output for the move forward multiple slightly

Comment: And also fixed another mistake in backward multiple... -_- sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've not mentioned anything about validation like if the given sequence of elements is not present in the original list, the ordering of the main list and given list etc. I've not considered any validations.

Before jumping into code, let's see how to crack the solution.
First, you need to identify the existing position of the given list in the main list.

```
move_list_pos = lis.index(move_list[0])
```

Now, check whether the given list to be moved forward or backward.

- If it needs to move backward, then theirs no change in the main list
  till the new positon, insert the given list, continue the main list except for the given list.
- If it needs to move forward, then the main list should be there
  except for the given list in the main list till the new position, add the
  given list, continue the main list from a new position to end.

---

Solution code:

```
def move(lis,move_list,pos):
    move_list_pos = lis.index(move_list[0])
    if pos<move_list_pos:
        return lis[:pos]+move_list+lis[pos:move_list_pos]+lis[move_list_pos+len(move_list):]
    else:
        return lis[:move_list_pos]+lis[move_list_pos+len(move_list):pos+1]+move_list+lis[pos+1:]
```

Comment: I've changed the naming convention to make code easy to understand.